# until today, does it include today

Tags: past-tense

> Until today, I have been getting on well with my boyfriend but this morning we had an argument and he made me cry

Is it possible to write that I don't think so:

"Until today" includes today so the statement is valid for today, or the second part of the sentence tells the reader the contrary :  this morning belongs to the past and the action is finished (the argument). The sentence will read better with past (had been getting or was getting)

May be "until today" does not include today

Comment: How could "until today" include today, if something else happened today that broke the pattern? This is logic, not English.

Comment: That is why I am asking thé question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [By vs Until vs Until then](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/132172/by-vs-until-vs-until-then) or [Until - ambiguity](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/138523/until-ambiguity) or [a lot of other options](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=until).

Comment: 'Until today' must necessarily include at least some of today. If you and your boyfriend were happy together until 00:00:01 today, and then you had an argument, you were happy for 1 second during today. If the argument happened at 23:59:59 yesterday, then you were happy until yesterday.

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? Please [edit] to provide a link if possible, or tell us the source. Also, when you say "*Is it possible to write that I don't think so*", Do you mean, "*Is it possible to write that? I don't think so*" ??

Comment: "Until today, I have been getting well with my boyfriend but this morning we had an argument and he made me cry" is ambiguous. it could mean that you had been getting on well, but no longer are, or it could mean that you are still getting on well but fear that may not continue to be the case (you can have an argument but still be getting on well in general). Use of "have been" suggests the latter.

Answer (score 3):

> 1: ***Until today** I had been getting on well with my boyfriend*

...implies I'm ***not*** getting on with him now (today). But in most contexts...

> 2: *This shop is [only] open **until today***

...implies the shop ***is*** open right now.

---

In short, exact context affects the possible meaning. And of course, part of the "context" is ***have/had been** getting on* in #1, and ***is** open* in #2.

Personally I can't really see any difference between
Present Perfect ***have been*** and Past Perfect ***had been*** in OP's context, but others may have different opinions.

---

Note that ***today*** has "duration", which could affect interpretation. But ***now*** is just an instant in time, so it's worth considering...

> 3: *I've never eaten sushi **until now***

...which is perfectly valid regardless of whether the speaker is looking at the sushi he's *just about to eat*, OR looking at the empty plate after he's *just finished eating* it.

Comment: So my example is valid

Comment: Yes. And according to [this usage chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Until+today+I+have+been%2CUntil+today+I+had+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) your *Present* Perfect is actually more idiomatic than my preferred *Past* Perfect *Until today I **had** been getting on...* But obviously in your context, the speaker is ***no longer*** getting on well (if she was, there wouldn't be any point in saying ***until today***). Whereas ***my*** example is ambiguous as regards whether I've ***yet*** eaten sushi at the exact moment of speaking.

Comment: "Until today, I have been" means this was true in the past and continues to be true, but may cease to be true after today. So it's not equivalent to "Until today, I had been", which indicates something which has already ceased to be true.

Comment: @StuartF: That's obviously the *logical* semantic difference, but there are more written instances of [*Until today I **have** heard nothing*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Until+today+I+have+heard+nothing%22) than there are of [*Until today I **had** heard nothing*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Until+today+I+had+heard+nothing%22). And I doubt anyone would include ***until today*** there if they ***hadn't*** already heard something ***today***. So I stand by my first comment, even though I wouldn't have expected to find that preference, before I saw the usage chart.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi! I upvoted your good answer! I left you 2 comments on other question. I still wait your reply.